# Pscp (putty) sometimes hangs during repeated ssh handshake

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, pscp

I have a Problem with the putty tool pscp.

I check if Linux VM (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4) "TARGET" is alive and store a timestamp on the TARGET in a file. I do this all 10s from a Windows VM (windows server 2016) "SOURCE".  The process is being started in Java by the following code:

```
// get a Process executing the instruction with cmd and 
terminate the process after 5s.
String instruction = "pscp.exe  -batch -i  C:\\User\\Me 
\\keys \\privatekey_Me.ppk -sshlog >C:\\User\\Me 
\\putty.log -scp TARGET:~/dir/file.txt file.txt"
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(instruction,null,dir);
if(!p.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) { //I want this to be 
5s instead of 3m, but for the question on >stackoverflow 
3m is clearer.
    p.destroy();
    throw new Exception("Connection took too long.");
  }
```

In general it works.

But it also fails consistently after 2m-10m (absolute max 20m – an extreme outlier, median is 4m). For 5s-2m pscp hangs, not crashes, hangs, eventually it recovers and carries on like nothing happened. This behaviour can be observed also by manually starting a pscp.exe – both the batch script and manual connection will then succeed at the same time.

For clarity:

```
>10:00:00 start, connection & copy success
>10:00:10 start, connection & copy success
>10:00:20 start, hanging
>10:00:30 hanging
>…
>10:01:30 connection & copy success
>10:01:40 start, connection & copy success
```

During this hanging periods, I pinged both directions (TARGET  SOURCE, SOURCE  TARGET) and there was no observable change in roundtriptime.

Here are two log files, the first from a successful manual connection (I terminated it when reaching the point where I would need to supply the passwort) and a log for a hanging connection (extracted before the connection recovered).

success

> Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: C:\Users\Me\putty.log
>   Event Log: Looking up host "TARGET"
>   Event Log: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port YYYY
>   Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.64
>   Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
>   Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
>   Outgoing packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
>   Incoming packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
>   Event Log: Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
>   Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
>   Outgoing packet #0x1, type 30 / 0x1e (SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT)
>   Incoming packet #0x1, type 31 / 0x1f (SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY)
>   Event Log: Host key fingerprint is: 
>   Event Log: ssh-rsa 2048 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>   Outgoing packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
>   Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
>   Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
>   Incoming packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
>   Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
>   Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
>   Outgoing packet #0x3, type 5 / 0x05 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x3, type 6 / 0x06 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT)
>   Outgoing packet #0x4, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x4, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
>   Event Log: Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
>   Event Log: Attempting GSSAPI authentication
>   Outgoing packet #0x5, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x5, type 60 / 0x3c (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_GSSAPI_RESPONSE)
>   Event Log: GSSAPI authentication initialisation failed
>   Event Log: The target was not recognized.
>   Outgoing packet #0x6, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Event Log: Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
>   Incoming packet #0x6, type 60 / 0x3c (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST)

Failure

> Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: C:\Users\Me\putty.log
>   Event Log: Looking up host "TARGET"
>   Event Log: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port YYYY
>   Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.64
>   Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
>   Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
>   Outgoing packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
>   Incoming packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
>   Event Log: Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
>   Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
>   Outgoing packet #0x1, type 30 / 0x1e (SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT)
>   Incoming packet #0x1, type 31 / 0x1f (SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY)
>   Event Log: Host key fingerprint is: 
>   Event Log: ssh-rsa 2048 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>   Outgoing packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
>   Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
>   Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
>   Incoming packet #0x2, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
>   Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
>   Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
>   Outgoing packet #0x3, type 5 / 0x05 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x3, type 6 / 0x06 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT)
>   Outgoing packet #0x4, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x4, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
>   Event Log: Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
>   Event Log: Attempting GSSAPI authentication
>   Outgoing packet #0x5, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Incoming packet #0x5, type 60 / 0x3c (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_GSSAPI_RESPONSE)
>   Event Log: GSSAPI authentication initialisation failed
>   Event Log: The target was not recognized.
>   Outgoing packet #0x6, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
>   Event Log: Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication

Long log short: the two are identical, except for the last Line which is only in the succes log:

Incoming packet #0x6, type 60 / 0x3c (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST)

It appears this packet causes the problem.  Maybe it gets lost sometimes? (but then it should not be so consistently after 2m-10m, right?)
I hope anyone can help me with this issue, as I have not a deep enouth understanding of the process to continue debuging.

For security reasons I may not use 'just any library'. Nativ features and well established programms are my main options.

Comment: Use a native Java SSH/SCP library (like JSch), instead of driving an external application.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you. However, for security reasons I must use trusted tools only for this authentification.